# Bind an end date using AngularJS and datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, datepicker

Hello, I have this scenario:
2 datepickers I use, have an AngularJS directive to load the datepickers.

How to use a start date to bind an end date?
(Ex: start: 22/01/2014 (selected by datepicker 1) end: 22/01/2014 (bind from datepicker 1, but can I use datepicker 2 to select another one?)

See the code:

```
<input id="AUT_MED_dataini" name="AUT_MED_dataini" data-ng-model="autorizacaoMedicao.AUT_MED_dataini" data-datainimed="" type="text" class="width100" /> a <input id="AUT_MED_datafim" name="AUT_MED_datafim" data-ng-model="autorizacaoMedicao.AUT_MED_datafim" data-datafimmed="" type="text" class="width100" />
```

JS code:

```
myApp.directive('datainimed', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(function() {
                element.datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    onSelect: function(date) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});

myApp.directive('datafimmed', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(function() {
                element.datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    setDate: '0',
                    onSelect: function(date) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

How to bind on a respect ng-models.

Comment: I am new to AngularJS myself, but can you not use the ng-pattern directive, then build the regular expression to only allow dates in your range?

Comment: i'm new too. How i do this ?! Can you give a example ?

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input  This has the ng-pattern described on the input, then you would need to Google for date formats to set a Regular Expression to.